# Android calling C++ function getting UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, c++

I have following function in my native-lib.cpp file:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_com_example_z_myapplication_MainActivity_convert32to64(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                             jlong l) {

// TODO
l = l + 76561197960265728L;
return l;
}
```

In my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
    public static native long convert32to64(long l);

    ...
}
```

I have a CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add.library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
```

However I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.example.z.myapplication.MainActivity.convert32to64(long) (tried Java_com_example_z_myapplication_MainActivity_convert32to64 and Java_com_example_z_myapplication_MainActivity_convert32to64__J)
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `extern "C"` for C++ JNI.

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_com_example_z_myapplication_MainActivity_convert32to64(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong l) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have just added extern "C", it still says the error

Comment: @TomDawn is the shared library being properly recompiled and is it accessible by the Java code in runtime? mind that the android sample suggests to comment out the native lib module after it's compiled once

Comment: I simply add extern "C" and click run to start running in simulator. Could you tell me how to recompile it please? Sorry maybe this is a dumb question

Comment: @TomDawn make sure that your lib module is uncommented in `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`, and, as a good practice, do `Build > Clean Project` before running it